# How to setup Google Cloud Messaging for Android? 

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement `Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)` by following the [demo](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html)

But i am unable to execute some command like `$ ant war`,`$ android update project --name GCMDemo -p . --target android-16`.

I am using `wamp server` and targetting Android 8+

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I have been able to implement GCM from the documentation and sample code. check http://android.amolgupta.in/2012/07/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial.html for the steps and downloadable code.

Comment: Please refer this URL, A simple Implementation of GCM. http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/

Comment: did you update constants with your API key for GCM?

Comment: Notice you need to get first to inter Google messaging key.

Comment: What error are you getting when you run these commands?

Comment: very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Comment: very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute `$ant war` command:

1. first you need to download and install [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) on your computer.
2. Then you should configurate your PATH and JAVA_HOME variables like it is described [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) (into "Installing Apache Ant" section).
3. And only after that you can execute `ant war` command into Windows command line (prompt).
   After `ant war` command `.war` file will be created.
4. then you can deploy and run your `.war` file on tomcat server for example. (create Java EE project, then download and install tomcat server, configurate paths, and run your project on tomcat server...)

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/