# push notification in android application

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Hi i wish to implement `push notification` in my own android application. how can i do? please give me some ideas....

This kind of broadcast receivers should receive messages even if my app is closed(like Gmail.here i receive one new message in my inbox means that time the notification message is displayed on top of my android device,clicked that notification message means directly go to inbox and view that message).

here i wish to insert one data on my database means the notification message is display on my android app even my app is closed.

Comment: You can check ["**Android Push Notification : Latest Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) - step by step complete tutorial**"](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-google-cloud.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html. You need to implement GCM.

**EDIT:**

To get notification even if app is in background, see [Android GCM (push notification): device doesn't receive notification if application is stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073449/android-gcm-push-notification-device-doesnt-receive-notification-if-applicat).

See [Android GCM basic implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438464/android-gcm-basic-implementation), http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html & [How to setup Google Cloud Messaging for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261000/how-to-setup-google-cloud-messaging-for-android)

Comment: it is helpful only.but i can't implement this.so please give me one sample example tutorial

Comment: the above above tutorial is already referred.i have developed successfully one listview using soap webservice.here i have to insert 2 item on my database means that time (2 new item is inserted) the notification message is automatically comes to the top, clicking the notification will take you directly to the app and display listview with the 2 new items also.it is perform even my app is closed also like gmail.in gmail got any new message means that time the notification message is displayed,clicked that notification message means directly go to inbox and view that message.how can i do.

Answer (score 0):

see http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html for detaily. There you find a tutorial and all the basic stuff