# Setting gcm for server side

Tags: java, android, ant, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up a GCM Demo Application. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

I am stuck trying to create a war file: In a shell window, go to the gcm-demo-server directory.

Generate the server's WAR file by running ant war:

I am using MAC how exactly can I create this war file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `ant war` command into `command prompt window`. (if you don't have Apache Ant you should install it).
Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261000/how-to-setup-google-cloud-messaging-for-android/12375853#12375853)  to similar question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222804/how-can-i-install-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x

Comment: in command line stand into folder with your gcm-demo-server project, and after that call `ant war` command. In Windows it looks like 1. `cd C:\pathToyourProject\gcm-demo-server` 2. `ant war`.  Just build.xml file is in your gcm-demo-server folder :)

Comment: i mean, because of build.xml file is into `gcm-demo-server` folder - you should make `gcm-demo-server` folder as current folder (into command line). Only after that you can call `ant war` command. (Otherwise `apache ant` will not find your `build.xml` file.)

Comment: In mac system have gcm-demo-server folder there in this path only./Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/extras/google/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-server.me also run this path after that run the ant war.that time also i have same error only.Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed.how can i get build successful message and get the gcm-demo.war file.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://github.com/minthubk/GCM-Demo
```

here is the link for gcm demo.you can see the demo and also see the steps